# Javascript pause all other Vimeo Videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, vimeo

I would like to have it so that when I play one Vimeo video the others on the page will be paused.

I tried using the froogaloop API but had little help.

Using the current code I got it working so that when I switch tabs I can pause all videos. Now I want to make it so that when I play one video, the others pause.

Right now the event listeners for detecting 'play' are not working correctly. I believe that is because they need to be in the `$(document).ready()` but they are stuck in the first `<script>` area, encapsulated in `$(function(){ })` which I believe is preventing it from interacting.

The code can be found here: [www.proclinica.com/preview](http://www.proclinica.com/preview)

This is the code I modified to control the vimeo and you can see the event listeners work here: http://jsfiddle.net/GxwEX/5/

Can someone at least help me get the event listeners to work on the proclinica website?

Comment: Stack Overflow questions are answered for free, please use another site if you want to offer money for code.

Comment: I'm so sorry I had no idea, I took the offer for payment out. Please forgive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do that isn't working. In your code (on your site), you have this:

```
$('.client_logo').click(function() {
    post('pause');
});
```

When I click one of the logo's, any running videos seem to pause just fine.

If you're trying to pause all playing videos when another is started by the user; I don't think I've seen anywhere in your code (either in the JSFiddle or on the site) where you're trying to do that. If you have; can you show us what you've tried to far?

And finally, just to answer at least one part of your question... `$(...)` is actually just a nice shortcut for `$(document).ready(...)`.

**Edit:**

From the [documentation](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js):

> If you're embedding and controlling multiple players on a page, you can give each player a `player_id` to tell them apart:
>
> `http://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID?api=1&player_id=vimeoplayer`

If you've set it, this `player_id` is passed along to any event listeners, like so:

```
function onMessageReceived(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var player_id = e.player_id;

    // Do stuff
}
```

You can use this to identify which video was started, and restart it after you've paused the others.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response -- I finally got the event listeners to work.
Now when you click the play button the function onmessagerecieved() detects if there is a 'play' event, if so it runs post('pause') which pauses every video including the current one.

I don't know how to exclude the one that I clicked. Can you help?